# Store application config variables to database

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is there any PHP open source class that can store application configuration variables in MySQL database, like Wordpress for example?
I would like to store and read something like this:

```
$config['name'] = "test1";
$config['name']['subname'] = "test2";
```

in MySQL database table, and database table need to look something like this

```
Id | Name      | Value   | Parent Name Id |
1  | 'name'    | 'test1' | null           |
2  | 'subname' | 'test2' | 1              |
```

etc.

Comment: I found solution here [link](https://github.com/dschreck/php-eav-example).

Answer (score 1):

That need not have a class style.
For example:

```
//config.php

    $config['name'] = "test1";
    $config['name']['subname'] = "test2";

//other php.

    require_once('{path to config.php}');
    echo $config['name'];
    echo $config['name']['subname'];
```

Comment: Yes I need to write these values to database because variable values will be changed by users, and I can not write this new values to the ini files on server but I can write it in database. Therefore, we need a class that's going to read and write these values into the database.

Comment: It does not make any sense to keep using the relational data base, Mysql, where you change the formatted data. In that case, I think I should write something like mongodb, a non-sql database. If you have to use mysql, it is possible to store varchar datatypes using string manipulation.